# почувствовать разницу inline и не inline метода

Tags: c++, inline

подскажите, а как мне изменить тела конструкторов классов A и B, чтобы почувствовать разницу по производительности inline и не inline функций ??? или же в современных железах - компиляторах разницы мы не добъёмся ?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1

#include <ctime>
#include clude <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
  int z;
  public:
    A();

};
class B {
   A a;
  public:
    B();

};

inline A::A() { cout << "Hi. I am A - constructor" << endl; };
inline B::B() {  cout << "Hi. I am B - constructor" << endl; };

int main() {
  std::time_t start;
  std::time_t end;
  std::time(&start);
  B b[95000];
  std::time(&end);
  
  cout <<"Delta="<<std::difftime(end, start) << endl;

}
```

Comment: `inline` - это не указание, это - просьба. Компилятор сам будет решать, что делать `inline`, а что нет.

Comment: На одном inline вместо вызова через call вы сэкономите время на call и ret. Это, может, десяток тактов. Учитывая, что эти функции ещё и вводом-выводом занимаются, разницы вы не увидите. Попробуйте прокрутить вызов/inline в цикле раз так миллион, тогда может быть и будет разница во времени. Только убедитесь в коде, что там, где inline, у вас действительно сгенерировался инлайн, а там, где нет - нет.

Comment: можно перед нужной функцией добавить `__declspec(noinline)` что бы не давать инлайнить и `__forceinline` что бы попытаться заставить заинлайнить (но это для студийного компилятора). и потом уже можно смотреть на разницу.

Comment: `inline` - это указание линкеру не жаловаться, когда функция встречается в разных единицах трансляции и выбирать произвольную из них, а не указание встраивать ее или нет.

Comment: это уже побочный эффект, который сделали фичей

Comment: самое тяжёлое это вывод на консоль. ваш конец строки `cout<<endl` обязывает делать `flush` потока, то есть полносьтю вывод буфера. Зачем вы такое сделали? Это уже проверка стойкости оконной системе всего-лишь.

Comment: это просто способ показать, что inline не вносит заметных изменений (потому что вывод кушает 99.9..9% всего